# UnsupportedOperationException while using BadgeDrawable with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm using `BadgeDrawable`with `BottomNavigationView` . But when I put a badge in an Icon of the bottomNavigationView I get this Exception

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 3: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0400db a=6}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:597)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getColorStateList(MaterialResources.java:76)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.TextAppearance.<init>(TextAppearance.java:85)
        at com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable$SavedState.<init>(BadgeDrawable.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable.<init>(BadgeDrawable.java:424)
        at com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable.createFromAttributes(BadgeDrawable.java:332)
        at com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable.create(BadgeDrawable.java:300)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.getOrCreateBadge(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:692)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(BottomNavigationView.java:689)
        at com.app.UI.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:129)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:241)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:131)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

I'm setting the number of badge in the `Observe` callback of the `LiveData` when request is success .

Here is my View

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/navigation_background_selector"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/text_color_drawer_selector"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        />
```

How I set number of the badge

```
int menuItemId = bottom_navigation.getMenu().getItem(1).getItemId();
BadgeDrawable badge = bottom_navigation.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId);
badge.setNumber(20);
```

And my Style

```
 <style name="Theme.app" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Yes , see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this Exception by changing my Theme

**From :**

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

**To :**

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
```